# How to add multiple lines to \author? or How to enable line breaks at \author?

Tags: line-breaking, koma-script, author

Since the university has different requirements from the template provided by Latex, I would like to use \author for a different purpose. To do this, it is necessary to use line breaks. Unfortunately, this does not seem to be intended.

Many thanks for your help and suggestions

Werrold

Notes:
Arial has been commented out.
Since \titlehead should consist of a graphic, this has also been commented out.

```
\documentclass[% document class
  paper=a4,%                
  12pt,%                        
  bibliography=totoc,%
  listof = totoc,%          
  index=totoc,%                 
  BCOR= 4 mm,%                  
  captions=tableheading,%   
  numbers=noenddot,%        
  parskip=half,%            
  DIV=calc,%                
  footnotes=multiple, %                
  final%                    
  %draft%               
  ]{scrreprt}

% requirements of the university 
  \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}         %zeilenabstand 
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}                          %zeilenabstand
\usepackage[left=30mm, right=25mm]{geometry}    %Seitenränder
\usepackage{showframe}                          %table must fit into frame !!!

% load necessary packages
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{luacode}
%\setromanfont{Arial}
%\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=jura2,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\usepackage{acronym}                        
 \usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

%\titlehead{
%\centering
%\includegraphics[scale=1.1]{XYZ}
%}
\setkomafont{subject}{\Large}
\subject{Bachelorthesis
\linebreak zur Erlangung des Grades
\linebreak Bachelor of Laws LL. B.
}
\title{Geldspeicher}
\subtitle{}
\date{}
\author{Fakultät II
\linebreak - unrechtmäßige Bereicherung -
\linebreak der
\linebreak Hochschule für kriminelle Aktivitäten
\linebreak Entenhausen
}
\setkomafont{publishers}{\normalsize}
\publishers{
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Verfasser: Bankjob Knack ~~& ~~Prüfer: Klaas Klever \\
Betrieb: Panzerknacker AG & ~~2. Prüfer: Mac Moneysac \\
Abgabetermin: 15.02.2024 & ~~Studienbeginn: 2021
\end{tabular}
}

\maketitle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't use `\and` inside `\author`, you can use `\\` to add extra material below the author:

```latex
\documentclass[% document class
  paper=a4,% Note: Already the default and therefore not needed.
  12pt,%                        
  bibliography=totoc,%
  listof = totoc,%          
  index=totoc,%                 
  BCOR= 4 mm,% Note: Makes no sense, because of using geometry and not using
             % option usegeometry!!!
  captions=tableheading,%   
  numbers=noenddot,%        
  parskip=half,%            
  DIV=calc,% Note: Makes no sense, because of using geometry and not using
           % option usegeometry!!!
  footnotes=multiple, %                
  final%
  %draft%               
  ]{scrreprt}

% requirements of the university 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}         %zeilenabstand 
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last} % Note: Makes no sense, because of the next line!!!
\usepackage[left=30mm, right=25mm]{geometry}    %Seitenränder
\usepackage{showframe}                          %table must fit into frame !!!

% load necessary packages
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}

\begin{document}

%\titlehead{
%\centering
%\includegraphics[scale=1.1]{XYZ}
%}
\setkomafont{subject}{\Large}
\subject{Bachelorthesis
\linebreak zur Erlangung des Grades
\linebreak Bachelor of Laws LL. B.
}
\title{Geldspeicher}
\subtitle{}
\date{}
\author{Fakultät II\\
- unrechtmäßige Bereicherung -\\
der\\
Hochschule für kriminelle Aktivitäten\\
Entenhausen
}
\setkomafont{publishers}{\normalsize}
\publishers{
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Verfasser: Bankjob Knack ~~& ~~Prüfer: Klaas Klever \\
Betrieb: Panzerknacker AG & ~~2. Prüfer: Mac Moneysac \\
Abgabetermin: 15.02.2024 & ~~Studienbeginn: 2021
\end{tabular}
}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please see also my additional comments. `\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}` has nothing to do with the “Zeilenabstand” but with the size of the text area and the margins. But because you are setting these using package `geometry` the command does not make any sense.

I've also removed several preamble code that is irrelevant for your problem.

With more complicated title pages I would suggest to not use `\maketitle` and misuse elements, but use a free designed content inside a `titlepage` environment. Using [package `uni-titlepage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/uni-titlepage) could also be an option. But in your case the package does not provide an already existing style, which is identical to what you want. So you would either have to adapt an existing style or define a new one or [request for a new one](https://github.com/komascript/uni-titlepage).

Comment: Thank you very much. I already took a look at the package uni-titlepage. I plan to continue studying after my bachelor's degree and therefore continue to deal with latex. That's why I want to create and contribute a template when I finish in July. I still have to revise the settings for the page layout, I copied the default settings from an old MWE, but I must also revise the current one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `tabular` or `\parbox` inside `\author` to covert multiline text into an `\hbox`.

```
\author{\begin{tabular}{c}
Fakultät II \\
unrechtmäßige Bereicherung -\\
der\\
Hochschule für kriminelle Aktivitäten\\
Entenhausen
\end{tabular}%
}
```